# K-means cluster, maximum size of cluster in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have 591 locations and I want to create 50 clusters where minimum and maximum size of the clusters should be 8 to 12 points using k-means cluster. Is there any possible way to adjust the cluster size range in QGIS? I have found a script in Python for QGIS but only minimum size is possible to adjust.